# MVVM Light ViewModelLocator

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM Light in my application, with multiple assemblies in the solution. 
How can I have a ViewModelLocator in each assembly without defining in App.xaml resources?

Typically ViewModelLocator is defined like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     <ResourceDictionary Source="/Sol1;component/GlobalResources.xaml" />
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   <viewModels:ViewModelLocator xmlns:main="clr-namespace:MainModule.ViewModel;assembly=MainModule" x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True"/> 
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I created a Resources.xaml in a class library within my solution like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:ModuleX="clr-namespace:ModuleX">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Common;component/CommonResources.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
<ModuleX:ViewMoldelLocator x:Key="ModuleXLocator" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

However, ModuleXLocator is not found:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
       ...
       DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource ModuleXLocator}}">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not 100% if I'm answering your question but I'll answer a similar problem I had and its the solution.  Hopefully its what you're looking for.

### Problem:

You've designed a wonderful little MVVMLight application (LittleApp) and now you want to use it as a UserControl/Page/Window in another project (BigApp).  The problem is LittleApp has its ViewModelLocator defined in its corresponding App.xaml which is not used for BigApp.  The result is LittleApp looks for its ViewModelLocator in "BigApp's App.xaml" and fails.

You also want to keep LittleApp working as a stand alone project and so don't want to mess with its design.

### Gives Possible Exceptions:

XMLParseException:  The ViewModelLocator defined in LittleApp's root node can't be found (because its defined in an unused App.xaml)

WPFError 40:  You've used the MVVMLight tool to create both apps and thus both Apps have an App.xaml with a ViewModelLocator called 'Locator' pointing to a ViewModel called 'Main'.  LittleApp will be able to resolve this but it will point to the wrong MainViewModel and thus have property conflicts.

### Solution:

You need to define LittleApp's ViewModelLocator as a resource in the root node of LittleApp's MainView.  So if your MainView is a UserControl called LittleApp/View/MainView.xaml it will look something like this.

```
<UserControl x:Class="LittleApp.View.MainView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:LittleApp.ViewModel"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
       .
       .  Your Control Design
       .
       .
       .
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now BigApp just needs to reference LittleApps assembly and add it as a namespace in the root node of the control you want to add it to.  Something like this.

```
<Page x:Class="BigApp.View.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"      
      xmlns:LittleView="clr-namespace:LittleApp.View;assembly=LittleApp"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid>
        <LittleView:MainView/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You definitely took me to the right way. Actually I added <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"/> in a LittleAppResources.xaml and then in each View I added a reference for that xaml through ResourceDictionary, as you did in the UserControl. :)

Comment: This answer directly addresses a problem I have, thank you! Question though: will this result in LittleApp's VML overriding BigApp's? How can I share data between the VMLs? (for example, I don't want each LittleApp window to have to re-load data the parent already loaded from disk, but I don't want multiple LittleApps to share state.

Comment: @metao You shouldn't be sharing information between VMLocators.  Each project should have one VML which links the views to their respective viewmodels.  If they have a parent child relationship the parent viewmodel should create and contain each child viewmodel and you can pass information directly between them or use a messenger service.  Then in the xaml the BigApp's datacontext will be (Locator.)Main (as set in app.xaml) and you can set the LittleApps datacontext as a binding to (Locator.)Main.LittleAppViewModel either in code or in BigApp's xaml.

Comment: @metao All of LittleApp's elements will inherit this new datacontext and populate the view correctly via its own bindings defined in its own project.  It's worth noting that if your using mvvmLight you can register LittleApp's MainViewModel in BigApps VML using the SimpleIoC - e.g SimpleIoc.Default.Register<LittleApp.ViewModel.MainViewModel>();.  Then you can just call the existing/new instance in BigApp's MainViewModel (for example in the constructor) LittleAppViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<LittleApp.ViewModel.MainViewModel>().  This is what you then bind as the datacontext.

Comment: @Josh C your answer was very helpful during my quest to improve my implementation of MVVM.  However, I'm having trouble getting the concept of a ViewModelLocator to work from XAML.  When I use your approach, databinding fails because it looks for the properties on the "Locator" object, instead of the ViewModel.  However if I assign the DataContext in code-behind using the SimpleIoc ServiceLocator, everything works.  Do you have any suggestions as to how I can get it to work from XAML?